# Huawei CPE B310 LAN IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, modem

I connected my laptop to my Huawei CPE B310 via ethernet. The IP address for the laptop was 192.168.8.100.
Then i connected my mobile via Wifi. When I check the WLAN status screen in the control panel of the router, I find that the IP address for my Mobile is 192.168.8.100.

My question: Why the mobile took my Laptop address? Where I can find, in the router control panel, the IP reserverd for the LAN port.

Comment: Were both the laptop and the mobile device connected at the same time or at separate times?  If connected simultaneously, then it's a problem.  It connected at separate times, might not be a problem.

Comment: Connected simultaneously

Comment: That should never happen if the Router is setup correctly as a DHCP server.  Either one of your devices is configured with a static address of 192.168.8.100 or your DHCP server is configured to only give out a single address (which is highly unlikely) or your router has a software bug (You should run the latest version for your router)...  Out of ideas with the information provided.